# How can I remove the booked area for undisplayed figure/text or plot in shiny?

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have a simple question that I want to display just "text" when the checkbox is unclicked. However, the undisplayed plot has already place to be displayed. I need to remove it.

[image]
[image]
     library(shiny)

```
   shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
     titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data")
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("bins",
              "Number of bins:",
              min = 1,
              max = 50,
              value = 30),
  checkboxInput("click","Plot")
),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
     mainPanel(
       splitLayout(plotOutput("distPlot"), h4("Just Text"))))))


library(shiny)

  shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
  if(input$click){
# generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
x    <- faithful[, 2]
bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

# draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   }
   else (return(0))})})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could just change your `mainPanel` to be a `conditionalPanel`. Replace your `mainPanel` code with this:

```
mainPanel(
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.click === true",
                   plotOutput("distplot")
  ),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.click === false",
                   h4("Just text...")
  )
)
```

Now, when your check the checkbox, the text box should disappear and your plot shows up.

Comment: It work so well. Thanks a lot.
However, i would like to use conditionalPanel for tabPanels which I describe my problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961072/how-can-i-design-main-panel